# `IonRouterOutlet` does not deep render in Ionic-React snapshot testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to do a snapshot of a component wrapped by Ionic React router and perform deep rendering. But `IonicRouterOutlet` doesn't seem to deep render in my case. Any suggestions how to fix this issue and perform a deep rendering successfully?

Here's my sample code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import { IonRouterOutlet } from '@ionic/react'
import { IonReactRouter } from '@ionic/react-router'

jest.mock('@capacitor/core', () => ({
  Plugins: {
    StatusBar: {
      setStyle: jest.fn()
    },
    Storage: {
      set: jest.fn(),
      get: () => ""
    }
  },
  StatusBarStyle: {
    Light: "LIGHT"
  },
}));

describe('component', () => {
  let component

  beforeEach(async () => {
    component = render(
      <IonReactRouter>
        <IonRouterOutlet>
          <div />
        </IonRouterOutlet>
      </IonReactRouter>
    )
  })

  describe('snapshot', () => {
    it('should match snapshot', () => {
      const { asFragment } = component
      expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot()
    })
  })
})
```

Here's my snapshot output:

```js
exports[`Login component snapshot should match snapshot 1`] = `
<DocumentFragment>
  <ion-router-outlet />
</DocumentFragment>
`;
```

As you can see, the `<div />` is not generated in snapshot output. So how to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you mocking Ionic React components somewhere?

Comment: @juliomalves there is a mock function, yes. I just updated the code above. Please have a look. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this documentation which i think would be helpful https://github.com/crossroads/app.goodchat.hk/wiki/Testing-Routing

Basically, as you have found using `IonReactRouter` & `IonRouterOutlet`  causes the JSDOM to output `<ion-router-outlet />` and not the full tree.

The workaround is to use React Router's  `Router` and `MemoryRouter` directly, depending on what you want to access e.g `history.location.pathname`.  `IonReactRouter` uses React Router under the hood so the behaviour and JSDOM output should match.